# ASP.NET web api 2 EnableCors Method not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I installed webapi2 and the version of the assemblies are installed successful with the message:

```
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3' to AT.Web.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.3' to AT.Web.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3' to AT.Web.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3' to AT.Web.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.2.3' to AT.Web.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.2.3' to AT.Web.
```

BUT in WebApiConfig.cs in register method, want to enable cors but there is no method "EnableCors",

Please suggest

Comment: NO LUCK SO FAR, Anyone ?? i am using vs2013

Answer (score 8):

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Esentially. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Comment: I already added that, see the messages from package console clearly saying that its installed.

Comment: No. you have added Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.2.3 not Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Comment: When i run this command "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors"
it says : 
AT.Web already has a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.2.3'.

Comment: Try this....

Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Also, make sure you have this using statement 

using System.Web.Http;

Comment: `Google is your friend` well Google brought me here

Comment: Thanks @user844705, I made the same mistake.

Comment: Enforcing -reinstall solved the issue (see above user844705'answer)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a reference to assembly System.Web.Http.Cors. This fixed the error for me.